# the react-google-login library use the Google Identity Services?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-signin

i'm using the react-google-login library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login/v/5.2.2) for javascript to give access to users to my site.

do you know if this library use the "Google Identity Services" or the "Google Sign-In Service"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This library
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login/v/5.2.2
is using "Google Sign-In Service"

For the "Google Identity Services" you can check:

https://github.com/MomenSherif/react-oauth